# AppCompatActivity not using colorPrimary for Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-styles

According to https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html , `colorPrimary` should set the action bar color.

This works when my `mainActivity` extends `Activity`, but it breaks when I extend instead `AppCompatActivity` (or the now-deprecated `ActionBarActivity`).

So for `AppCompatActivity` I must use:

`values/style.xml`

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MaterialTeal800</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MaterialTeal500</item>
    <!--<item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/MaterialLightPrimary</item>-->
    <!--<item name="colorDivider">@color/MaterialDivider</item>-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/MaterialDeepOrange500</item>
    <!--<item name="colorAccentPressed">@color/MaterialDeepOrange800</item>-->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/MaterialSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
</style>
<style name="TitleText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

which colors the status bar correctly, but *NOT* the action bar.

And (for v21, anyway) for `Activity` it works with

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar -->
    <!-- Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/MaterialTeal800</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/MaterialTeal500</item>
    <!--<item name="android:colorPrimaryLight">@color/MaterialLightPrimary</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/MaterialSecondary</item>
    <!--<item name="android:colorDivider">@color/MaterialDivider</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/MaterialDeepOrange500</item>
</style>
```

If I don't use `Activity` and use `AppCompatActivity` instead, it crashes on launch, saying:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I'd like to run with `AppCompatActivity` for, well, compatibility, but I can't figure out why it's not picking up the color (yet the same code works great with Activity -- and I'd love to use all the newer options on API 21+). It seems wrong that it'd pick up the status bar but I'd need to manually override a custom style on the action bar (a-la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492846/action-bar-title-icon-not-using-theme-color)). Am I stuck picking and choosing? No Material themes or transitions, or backward compatibility?

Note this is **not** a toolbar. This is the action bar -- I know I can use `android:background` on an added toolbar element.

### Update

Looks like I can get the actionbar to color with `AppCompatActivity` by dropping the v21 `android:` namespace, but still get the crash if I try to use the real material theme ...

Comment: Get rid of all the `@` signs in front of `@android`. And, for the `appcompat-v7` ones, get rid of `@android:` entirely.

Comment: @CommonsWare Exactly! It was the at android: entirely! Thank you Mr. Murphy!

Answer (score 2):

Here you should remove android: prefix for app compat theme like:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MaterialTeal800</item>
```

and in styles-v21

```
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/MaterialTeal800</item>
```

Comment: OK, that fixes the color, but I have to descend from the appcompat rather than the material theme ... don't suppose I can have my cake and eat it too?